# Split strings by 2nd space

Tags: python, string, split

Input :

```
"The boy is running on the train"
```

Output expected:

```
["The boy", "boy is", "is running", "running on", "on the", "the train"]
```

What is the easiest solution to achieve this in python.

Comment: Koustav Ghosal's solution is the fastest, see my edit.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You split on all spaces, then rejoin the pairs:

```
words = inputstr.split()
secondwords = iter(words)
next(secondwords)

output = [' '.join((first, second)) 
          for first, second in zip(words, secondwords)]
```

Demo:

```
>>> inputstr = "The boy is running on the train"
>>> words = inputstr.split()
>>> secondwords = iter(words)
>>> next(secondwords)  # output is ignored
'The'
>>> [' '.join((first, second)) for first, second in zip(words, secondwords)]
['The boy', 'boy is', 'is running', 'running on', 'on the', 'the train']
```

Answer (score 10):

```
line="The boy is running on the train"
words=line.split()
k=[words[index]+' '+words[index+1] for index in xrange(len(words)-1)]
print k
```

**Output**

```
['The boy', 'boy is', 'is running', 'running on', 'on the', 'the train']
```

Comment: Wow !I didn't expect this much ! Thanks :)

Comment: I like this solution best, but not because of performance reasons. I just think this is the simplest and easiest to understand.

Comment: @Koustav I find it's a little flaw to use the identifier ``c`` to designate an integer: that creates a momentary confusion because one thinks first that it designates a character. And, as Paul McGuire pointed to it, it would be better with ``xrange``

Comment: I changed c to 'index'. I hope that's more intuitive now. I also changed the range to xrange. But in Python 3 one must use 'range' only for obvious reasons. 

Thanks for all your effort and remarks.

Answer (score 3):

```
import re

s = "The boy is running on the train"

print map(' '.join,re.findall('([^ \t]+)[ \t]+(?=([^ \t]+))',s))
```

### Edit

Koustav Ghosal's solution is the fastest:

```
import re
from time import clock
from itertools import izip
from collections import defaultdict

s = "The boy is    running on the train"

z = 200
p = '%-9.6f %6.1f%%  %s'
rgx = re.compile('([^ \t]+)[ \t]+(?=([^ \t]+))')
R = defaultdict(list)

for rep in xrange(3000):

    t0 = clock()
    for i in xrange(z):
        map(' '.join,re.findall('([^ \t]+)[ \t]+(?=([^ \t]+))',s))
    te1 = clock()-t0
    R['e1'].append(te1)

    t0 = clock()
    for i in xrange(z):
        map(' '.join,rgx.findall(s))
    te2 = clock()-t0
    R['e2'].append(te2)

    t0 = clock()
    for i in xrange(z):
        words = s.split()
        secondwords = iter(words)
        next(secondwords)
        [' '.join((first, second))
         for first, second in zip(words, secondwords)]
    tM1 = clock()-t0
    R['M1'].append(tM1)

    t0 = clock()
    for i in xrange(z):
        words = s.split()
        secondwords = iter(words)
        next(secondwords)
        [' '.join((first, second))
         for first, second in izip(words, secondwords)]
    tM2 = clock()-t0
    R['M2'].append(tM2)

    t0 = clock()
    for i in xrange(z):
        words = s.split()
        secondwords = iter(words)
        next(secondwords)
        [' '.join(x)
         for x in izip(words, secondwords)]
    tM3 = clock()-t0
    R['M3'].append(tM3)

    t0 = clock()
    for i in xrange(z):
        words=s.split()
        [words[c]+' '+words[c+1] for c in range(len(words)-1)]
    tK1 = clock() - t0
    R['K1'].append(tK1)

    t0 = clock()
    for i in xrange(z):
        words=s.split()
        [words[c]+' '+words[c+1] for c in xrange(len(words)-1)]
    tK2 = clock() - t0
    R['K2'].append(tK2)

tmax = min(R['e1'])
for k,s in (('e1','eyquem with re.findall(pat,string)'),
            ('e2','eyquem with compiled_regex.findall(string)'),
            ('M1','Martijn Pieters'),
            ('M2','Martijn Pieters with izip'),
            ('M3','Martijn Pieters with izip and direct join'),
            ('K1','Koustav Ghosal'),
            ('K2','Koustav Ghosal with xrange')):
    t = min(R[k])
    print p % (t,t/tmax*100,s)
```

result with Python 2.7

```
0.007127   100.0%  eyquem with re.findall(pat,string)
0.004045    56.8%  eyquem with compiled_regex.findall(string)
0.003887    54.5%  Martijn Pieters
0.002522    35.4%  Martijn Pieters with izip
0.002152    30.2%  Martijn Pieters with izip and direct join
0.002030    28.5%  Koustav Ghosal
0.001856    26.0%  Koustav Ghosal with xrange
```

Comment: If you want to focus on speed as a measure of goodness, use the timeit module. After changing Martijn Peters' solution to remove tuple unpacking/repacking, and changing Koustav Ghosal's to use xrange instead of range, I can get these test times to fluctuate where sometimes Martijn's is faster, sometimes Koustav's is faster. timeit will run multiple tests, throw out extrema, and give an average time. Still not perfect, but a bit better than basing your choice on a single run of code.

Comment: @Paul McGuire I dropped to use timeit because 1/ I never remind the details of its use 2/ I still have not fully understood what exactly does ``Timer.timeit`` 3/ There's a note in ``Timer.repeat`` notice in the doc that the probable best measure of a an execution's time for a code snippet is the lowest value among the resulting time of several repetition of the snippet and that _"you should look at the entire vector and apply common sense rather than statistics"_ So instead of statistics done by ``Timer.repeat``, I prefer to use clock that is perfectly justified, IMO, by the following citation

Comment: @Paul McGuire ``time.clock()`` _"this is the function to use for benchmarking Python or timing algorithms."_ for Linux system, _"The resolution is typically better than one microsecond."_ for Windows system (http://docs.python.org/2/library/time.html#time.clock)

Comment: When I measure times with ``clock()``, I don't base the conclusion on only a run of code. Even when I give an answer on SO that doesn't perform itself the repetition of several measures, I run it several times and I select the run that seems to me to give the lowest values for all the execution times; or even, I select the lowest execution's time for each code snippet on several repetition and I group thm to compare the minimums obtained on several runs.

Comment: @Paul MacGuire Taking account of your remark, I modified my above answer to make the code do itself all this work. - The result is that Koustav's solution is still the best

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively, a solution with [`itertools.combinations`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.combinations):

```
>>> s = "The boy is running on the train"
>>> seen = set()
>>> new = []
>>> for tup in itertools.combinations(s.split(), 2):
...     if tup[0] not in seen:
...             new.append(' '.join(tup))
...             seen.add(tup[0])
... 
>>> print new
['The boy', 'boy is', 'is running', 'running on', 'on the', 'the train']
```

Although this really isn't what `itertools.combinations` should be used for :p.