# Python split string after every 2 white spaces

Tags: python

Im trying to split a string after two white spaces but im doing wrong.

**String :**

```
FN 318488 FO 318488 FP 318488 FR 318488 FS 318488
```

**My code :**

```
string.split(" ")
```

**My output :**

```
['FN', '318488', 'FO', '318488', 'FP', '318488', 'FR', '318488', 'FS', '318488', 'FU', '318488', 'FV', '318488', 'FW', '318488', 'FX', '318488', 'FY', '318488', 'FZ', '318488']
```

**I want output like this**

```
['FN 318488', 'FO 318488', 'FP 318488' ,'FR 318488', 'FS 318488']
```

How i can split string after two white spaces. any idea?

Comment: you can make your own function to combine the strings you want after splitting, or make your own split function

Comment: You mean to split the string every-second-space. There is an answer for that already... https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18546338/split-strings-by-2nd-space

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way to approach this would be to rejoin pairs of items after splitting on every space.  You can do this pretty easily by taking two different slices of alternating items and zipping them:

```
>>> string = "FN 318488 FO 318488 FP 318488 FR 318488 FS 318488"
>>> tokens = string.split(" ")
>>> [" ".join(pair) for pair in zip(tokens[::2], tokens[1::2])]
['FN 318488', 'FO 318488', 'FP 318488', 'FR 318488', 'FS 318488']
```

Answer (score 1):

This is most suited to parsing with a regular rexpression:

```
import re

string = 'FN 318488 FO 318488 FP 318488 FR 318488 FS 318488'
print(re.findall(r'\S+\s\S+', string))
```

This outputs:

```
['FN 318488', 'FO 318488', 'FP 318488', 'FR 318488', 'FS 318488']
```